# scraping python with asp

Tags: python-3.x, beautifulsoup

i actually work in python. I need to collect the following information from this website 
http://appweb2.cndh.org.mx/SNA/ind_Autoridad_SM_3.asp?Id_Aut=1063&Id_Estado=10&valorEF=317

I tried using requests

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import urllib.request
r=requests.post('http://appweb2.cndh.org.mx/SNA/ind_Autoridad_SM_3.asp?Id_Aut=1063&Id_Estado=10&valorEF=317')
print(r.url)
```

the output is

```
http://appweb2.cndh.org.mx/SNA/inicio.asp
```

always take the home page. i need help. thanks

Answer (score 0):

The cookie has to be passed with the request to get the proper response as the server identifies the request page with cookie only.

Refer the code below.

```
import requests
url = 'http://appweb2.cndh.org.mx/SNA/ind_Autoridad_SM_3.asp?Id_Aut=1063&Id_Estado=10&valorEF=317'
headers={'Accept':'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8','Accept-Encoding':'gzip, deflate','Accept-Language':'en-US,en;q=0.9','Cache-Control':'max-age=0','Connection':'keep-alive','Cookie':'ASPSESSIONIDASTTTRTA=DIKNJIGADBLCIMCOKEMONJCH','Host':'appweb2.cndh.org.mx','Upgrade-Insecure-Requests':'1','User-Agent':'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/68.0.3440.106 Safari/537.36'}
page = requests.get(url, headers=headers).content
print(page)
```